# How to exclude particular user for schdule trigger in ccnet while IfModificationExists is true including it and false excluding it with TFS.

Tags: triggers, cruisecontrol.net, schedule

I have situation where my project checkin some changes during build. I also have scheduled trigger for build whenever there is change in modifications in TFS/VSTS source control. My problem is that, it automatically scheduled triggers build because of changes made during last build Hence, I am unable to achieve what I want to achieve. I want to make sure build is triggered when there is changes for scheduled build by development team and not my own build. Any idea how can i exclude myself while CCNET is detecting changesin TFS/VSTS source control?

Answer (score 0):

What file or files are being modified and checked in by the build server?  If the checkins are being made to a single location, you can limit the areas that ccnet monitors.  You may need to use the [Multi Source Control Block](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Multi_Source_Control).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Filtered Source Control Block](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered) which is specifically designed for that purpose